# Cannot install module in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, error

I can't install any module in Magento 2 with the composer. Here are the steps I used to install:

Navigated to the root directory of my Magento 2 installation folder and follow these steps:

Install via packaging

composer require `pagseguro/magento2`

Executed

> 1. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
>    2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>    3. chmod 777 -R var/ pub/
>    4. composer update pagseguro/magento2
>    5. composer update pagseguro/pagseguro-php-sdk
>    6. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>    7. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

But when I navigated to `STORES -> CONFIGURATION -> SALES -> PAYMENT METHODS`

The module isn't exist.

I tried, but it's not working. My magento directory is: `public_html/clubedental/loja ...`

Again, I tried the execution pointed from `public_html/clubedental/loja/bin/magento` as below

> 1. php public_html/clubedental/loja/bin/magento setup:upgrade
> 2. php public_html/clubedental/loja/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

But still its not appearing.

Comment: Could you try clear cache in Magento Admin.

Comment: Unfortunately Nothing :/

Comment: For pagseguro specifically I would go for [this one](https://pagseguro.ricardomartins.net.br/magento2/wizard.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the DB of the site, take a look at the `setup_module` table to see if your module is showing up there. It should have the name and the current module version. If it's not showing up in that table, then your configuration files are incorrect. A module only requires two files to be registered:

`app/code/{{vender_name}}/{{module_name}}/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="{{vender_name}}_{{module_name}}" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

and

`app/code/{{vender_name}}/{{module_name}}/registration.php`

```
<?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        '{{vender_name}}_{{module_name}}',
        __DIR__
    );
```

If your module is registered correctly, then your next step is de-bugging the module's code. I would recommend looking at the layout xml files and the controller files that should be hitting, as this is the first step in any module's life cycle.